# Renaming folders using VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to rename folders based upon a template that a user will fill out. The user will specify the old name of the folder and what it will be updated to. There are bunch of sub folders that also get the name change.

I have confirmed that the folders exist and in the locations that they should be so I don't understand why this is failing. I have also tried using FileSystem objects and get the same problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub UpdateMain()

    'string capture variables
    Dim currentLocation As String
    Dim currentName As String
    Dim customerNumber As String
    Dim newName As String

    'path creation variables
    Dim rootPath As String
    Dim currentPath As String
    Dim newPath As String

    'counter variables
    Dim i As Integer

    With wsUpdate
        currentLocation = .Range("B1")
        currentName = .Range("B2")
        customerNumber = .Range("B3")
        newName = .Range("B5")
    End With

    'create path and folder for the root folder
    rootPath = currentLocation & "\" & currentName & " (" & customerNumber & ")"

    'edit all subfolders prior to root folder
    i = 0
    With wsUpdate.Range("A8")
        Do Until .Offset(i, 0) = ""
                If .Offset(i, 1) = "Customer" Then
                    currentPath = rootPath & "\" & currentName & " " & .Offset(i, 0)
                    newPath = rootPath & "\" & newName & " " & .Offset(i, 0)
                Else
                    currentPath = rootPath & "\" & currentName & " " & .Offset(i, 1) & "\" & currentName & " " & .Offset(i, 0)
                    newPath = rootPath & "\" & newName & " " & .Offset(i, 1) & "\" & newName & " " & .Offset(i, 0)
                End If
                Call FolderNameEdit(currentPath, newPath)
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With

    'edit root folder
    currentPath = currentLocation & "\" & currentName & " (" & customerNumber & ")"
    newPath = currentLocation & "\" & newName & " (" & customerNumber & ")"
    Call FolderNameEdit(currentPath, newPath)

End Sub

Sub FolderNameEdit(currentPath As String, newPath As String)
    Name currentPath As newPath
End Sub
```

I keep getting

> Run-time error '53': File not found.

The error occurs on line:

```
Name currentPath as newPath
```

Comment: If the error message is RTE 53 then check `currentPath` and `newPath` at run time. Do the variables really contain the values you expect?

Comment: Or start running your code by F8, and keep checking what your variables are storing.

Comment: See my comment is the answer below. I have the correct values being passed to the called sub but a null value is returned on the if statement. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check folders before renaming:

```
Sub FolderNameEdit(currentPath As String, newPath As String)
    If Dir(currentPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        ' error
    ElseIf Dir(newPath, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
        ' error
    Else
        Name currentPath As newPath
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I updated the called sub to what you have above. `currentPath` has the correct value being passed but the logic branch goes to `If Dir(currentPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then`  Why is it showing as null when `currentPath` has a value?

Comment: @jive14 `Dir(currentPath, vbDirectory)` returns nullstring when `currentPath` is not an existing directory. So the logic is: first we check if the original directory exists, then we check if the target directory does not exist, and if both are true then `Name`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the logic. I'm confused because the directory exists (I'm looking at it while I step through the code) and the `currentPath` variable holds the exact string it needs to be, yet it can't find it? How do I solve this?

Comment: ,Scratch the comment about, I got it to make it through the logic to the `Name` keyword but it is still failing with the same error (Run-time error '53': File not found.) Any other ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. newPath was  the problem. It had a value I did not expect.